# TensorFlow: dimension error. how to debug?

Tags: runtime-error, tensorflow, dimension

I'm a beginner with TF

I've tried to adapt a code which is working well with some other data (noMNIST) to some new data, and i have a dimensionality error, and i don't know how to deal with it.

To debug, i'm trying to use `tf.shape` method but it doesn't give me the info i need...

```
def reformat(dataset, labels):
  #dataset = dataset.reshape((-1, num_var)).astype(np.float32)
  # Map 2 to [0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ...], 3 to [0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ...]
  labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
  return dataset, labels
train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(train_dataset, train_labels)
valid_dataset, valid_labels = reformat(valid_dataset, valid_labels)
test_dataset, test_labels = reformat(test_dataset, test_labels)
print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)
type(train_dataset)
```

> Training set (790184, 29) (790184, 39) Validation set (43899, 29)
>   (43899, 39) Test set (43899, 29) (43899, 39)

```
# Adding regularization to the 1 hidden layer network
graph1 = tf.Graph()
batch_size = 128

num_steps=3001

import datetime
startTime = datetime.datetime.now() 

def define_and_run_batch(beta):

    num_RELU =1024

    with graph1.as_default():

      # Input data. For the training data, we use a placeholder that will be fed
      # at run time with a training minibatch.
      tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                        shape=(batch_size, num_var))
      tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
      tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
      tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

      # Variables.
      weights_RELU = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([num_var, num_RELU]))

      print(tf.shape(weights_RELU) ) 


      biases_RELU = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_RELU]))
      weights_layer1 = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([num_RELU, num_labels]))
      biases_layer1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))

      # Training computation.
      logits_RELU = tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights_RELU) + biases_RELU
      RELU_vec = tf.nn.relu(logits_RELU)
      logits_layer = tf.matmul(RELU_vec, weights_layer1) + biases_layer1                  
      # loss = tf.reduce_mean(
      #        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits_layer, tf_train_labels))
      cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits_layer, tf_train_labels,name="cross_entropy")
      l2reg = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(weights_RELU))+tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(weights_layer1))
      # beta = 0.005
      loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy+beta*l2reg)

  # Optimizer.
      optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3).minimize(loss)

      # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
      train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits_layer)
      print("ok")  

      print(tf.shape(weights_RELU) ) 
      valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(
        tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu((tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights_RELU) + biases_RELU)),weights_layer1)+biases_layer1)



      test_prediction =tf.nn.softmax(
        tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu((tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights_RELU) + biases_RELU)),weights_layer1)+biases_layer1)

    with tf.Session(graph=graph1) as session:

      tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
      print("Initialized")
      for step in range(num_steps):

        # Pick an offset within the training data, which has been randomized.
        # Note: we could use better randomization across epochs.
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
        # Generate a minibatch. 
        batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        # Prepare a dictionary telling the session where to feed the minibatch.
        # The key of the dictionary is the placeholder node of the graph to be fed,
        # and the value is the numpy array to feed to it.
        feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
        #

        _, l, predictions, logits = session.run(
          [optimizer, loss,train_prediction,logits_RELU], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        if (step % 500 == 0):
          print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
          print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
          print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(
            valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
      test_acc = accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels)
      print("Test accuracy: %.1f%%" % test_acc)

      print('loss=%s' % l)
    x = datetime.datetime.now() - startTime
    print(x)
    return(test_acc,round(l,5))

define_and_run_batch(0.005)
```

> Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32) ok Tensor("Shape_1:0",
>   shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        94     return(test_acc,round(l,5))
>        95 
>   ---> 96 define_and_run_batch(0.005)
>
> in define_and_run_batch(beta)
>        54       print(tf.shape(weights_RELU) )
>        55       valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(
>   ---> 56         tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu((tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights_RELU) + biases_RELU)),weights_layer1)+biases_layer1)
>        57 
>        58
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.pyc
>   in matmul(a, b, transpose_a, transpose_b, a_is_sparse, b_is_sparse,
>   name)
>       949                                    transpose_a=transpose_a,
>       950                                    transpose_b=transpose_b,
>   --> 951                                    name=name)
>       952 
>       953 sparse_matmul = gen_math_ops._sparse_mat_mul
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.pyc in _mat_mul(a, b, transpose_a, transpose_b, name)
>       684   """
>       685   return _op_def_lib.apply_op("MatMul", a=a, b=b, transpose_a=transpose_a,
>   --> 686                               transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
>       687 
>       688
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.pyc
>   in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
>       653         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
>       654                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
>   --> 655                          op_def=op_def)
>       656         outputs = op.outputs
>       657         return _Restructure(ops.convert_n_to_tensor(outputs), output_structure)
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc
>   in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs,
>   op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)    2040
>   original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)    2041     if
>   compute_shapes:
>   -> 2042       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)    2043     self._add_op(ret)    2044
>   self._record_op_seen_by_control_dependencies(ret)
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc
>   in set_shapes_for_outputs(op)    1526       raise RuntimeError("No
>   shape function registered for standard op: %s"    1527
>   % op.type)
>   -> 1528   shapes = shape_func(op)    1529   if len(op.outputs) != len(shapes):    1530     raise RuntimeError(
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/common_shapes.pyc
>   in matmul_shape(op)
>        87   inner_a = a_shape[0] if transpose_a else a_shape[1]
>        88   inner_b = b_shape[1] if transpose_b else b_shape[0]
>   ---> 89   inner_a.assert_is_compatible_with(inner_b)
>        90   return [tensor_shape.TensorShape([output_rows, output_cols])]
>        91
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.pyc
>   in assert_is_compatible_with(self, other)
>        92     if not self.is_compatible_with(other):
>        93       raise ValueError("Dimensions %s and %s are not compatible"
>   ---> 94                        % (self, other))
>        95 
>        96   def merge_with(self, other):
>
> ValueError: Dimensions Dimension(29) and Dimension(30) are not
>   compatible

the whole code is on my github
https://github.com/FaguiCurtain/Kaggle-SF
the Udacity Assignment 3 file is working

the original data is here
https://www.kaggle.com/c/sf-crime/data

in Udacity, the data were images and each image was a 28x28 matrix which was reformatted into flattened vectors of size 784

in the Kaggle-SF file, i am feeding vectors of size 29, and labels can take 39 different values.

thanks for your help

Comment: The only thing that have Dimensions (29) and Dimensions (30) in the problematic code `tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu((tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights_RELU) + biases_RELU)),weights_layer1)+biases_layer1)` is tf_valid_dataset, and weights_RELU. Try ensuring that tf_valid_dataset has the correct shape.

Comment: which one has dimensions  29, 30 ? how can i printout the dimensions ? i was expecting both vectors to have dimensions 29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In debug mode you can check shapes of you Tensors.
by the way you error is valid_prediction assignment. to make it better for debugging and reading it's better to define each step in a separate line. you are using 4 operation in 1 line. BTW in debug mode (for example in Pycharm) you can inspect the element and check what is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

To check the dimensions, you can directly print the tensors. When you print the tensors, you can view the dimensions. I suggest if you are a beginner, try using the 'tf.layers' package which contains high level wrappers for the various layers one would need to build a CNN in tensorflow. By using this, you can avoid having to deal with the various low level operations like 'matmul' and adding bias for example. The activations can also be directly applied by the layers without having to implement it manually.

As far as debugging is concerned, from the code since you have merged the operations, its hard to see what is going on under the hood unless we can use a proper debugger. If you are not using an IDE, I suggest using 'pudb'.